# JPA make a part of the composite foreign key part of primary key

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I was looking at all the possible Google searches and Stackoverflow searches but couldn't find what I was looking for. My problem is that there is a class A and a class B, class A has a composite primary key and class B has a primitive primary key. These classes (tables) are joined with a class called C, I need this because there is other data with the join (examples at the bottom). In class C I obviously have class B's and A's primary keys as foreign keys, but I need the first property of the class B's composite key and A's foreign key to be the primary key in class C.

It is kinda hard to understand it with just text so here is the example:

```
public class CompositeId implements Serializable {
    private Long id;

    private Long version;

    // Other stuff...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(CompositeId.class)
public class A {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Id
    private Long version;

    private String name;

    private String creatorName;

    // Other stuff...
}

@Entity
public class B {
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    // Othet stuff...
}

public class CompositeJoinId implements Serializable {
    private Long aId; // Should equal to aReference's id property.

    private Long bId; // Should equal to bReference's id property.

    // Other stuff...
}

@IdClass(CompositeJoinId.class)
@Entity
public class C {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="a_version", referencedColumnName="version")
    })
    private A aReference;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B bReference;

    private Long day;

    // Other stuff...
}
```

Is there a way to make this happen? All my finding use only a class where both of the foreign composite keys are used, but I only need/want one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question; but I would map your classes like this (the primary difference being `CompositeJoinId`):

```
public class CompositeId implements Serializable {
    private Long id;

    private Long version;

    // Other stuff...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(CompositeId.class)
public class A {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Id
    private Long version;

    private String name;

    private String creatorName;

    // Other stuff...
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    // Othet stuff...
}

public class CompositeJoinId implements Serializable {
    private Long aId;

    private Long bReference; // matches name of @Id attribute and type of B PK

    // Other stuff...
}

@IdClass(CompositeJoinId.class)
@Entity
public class C {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "a_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Long aId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B bReference;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="a_version", referencedColumnName="version")
    })
    private A aReference;

    private Long day;

    // Other stuff...
}
```

These are examples of derived identities; and derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: This way my primary key in the C class will be A.id, A.version and B.id and I only need/want A.id and B.id. That's why I only used the ids in the composite join id class. So unfortunately this will not work for me.

Comment: Even though you do not need/want `A.id`, you can still tell JPA to use it as part of the C's id; as it can still be used by JPA to uniquely identify a C instance. Unless you are using your JPA mappings to generate your DDL (which is ill-advised :-), there should be no problem with these mappings. Do they cause any problems when you use them?

Comment: That's thing, I don't want to write my own database scripts, because then I could just use plain JDBC... So yea I am generating my database from these models and that's why I'm stuck. Do you have any other way to do this? If I wrote my sql script myself and specify that Class C has primary key of A.id and B.id then what would JPA do?

Comment: You are seriously underestimating JPA if you think it simply provides a way to generate your database. But you are not alone.... :-( Anyway: you could try mapping a read-only field to the appropriate column. I will change my answer to reflect something that might work.

Comment: I know it can do things I don't even know of, but at the moment I don't need those features. I just need to correctly generate the database from the models, thanks for your edit, I will check it no later than tomorrow. Thanks again.